# PowerShell strip all characters after first tab

Tags: powershell

I have a file I am trying to import from. The first column is an IDnum, Second is Name, Third is Version. What I want is just the IDNum column. The file is tab delimited so I was wondering how do I capture only the first column before the tab? The rest of the text on each line is not needed. The line looks like this:

`4809490    WebGoat         5.0`

So in this example, I only want 4809490. I do not need the rest of that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via Select-String as a one-liner.

```
Select-String -Path file.txt -Pattern '^\w+' -AllMatches |%{$_.Matches.Value} > newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I sat back and thought about it and found a way myself too :)

```
ForEach ($line in $content) { 
$thisappid = $line.Split("`t")
Write-Host $thisappid.GetValue(0)
}
```

Those are good answers as well so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the [Import-CSV](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113341) with a specified tab delimiter to load the file and select only the first column, or you can use the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet to load the file, iterate over it using [ForEach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) and use a `regex` to extract the `ID`:

```
Get-Content 'PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE' | ForEach-Object { 
    [regex]::Match($_, '\d+').Groups[0].Value 
}
```